# Como fazer uma consulta no Banco de Dados Mysql pelo filtro de: nos últimos 3 dias?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta de usuários que entraram no meu Banco de Dados nos últimos 3 dias mas não tenho retorno
$condicaoData = date('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
$dataa = $condicaoData - '0000-03-00 00:00:00';

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx");
$query = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE data >= '$dataa' ORDER BY ID DESC";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

Obs: Minha data no Banco de dados está assim: 2020-10-08 20:20:5 (Timestamp)

Comment: Já tentou: `DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 DAY);`?

Comment: Olá Skatethefut10, existem outras perguntas sobre data, basta trocar o numero de dias pelo numero desejado.

Comment: Ainda não tentei esse método DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 3 DAY); O Interval é default? Obs: Esqueci de colocar na thread mas o formato da minha data está assim: 2020-10-08 20:20:5

Comment: Consulte o manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html para determinar qual a função que melhor se adequa a suas necessidades.